# How would you get this data in unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

```
{"country":{"code":"NZ"}}
```

How would you store this data in a unity class?

Something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

[Serializable]
public class GDRPClass
{
    public string country;
    public string code;
}
```

I dont think that is right for a double {} though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always a very good starting point: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com)!

just make sure to use fields instead of properties and mark the clases `[Serializable]`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Country
{
    public string code;
}

[Serializeable]
public class GDRPClass
{
    public Country country;
}
```

You can call the classes/structs whatever you like, but the field names have to match!

---

In this simple case the structure is easily explained since the [data types in JSON](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvjsn/json-data-types.html) are very limited. You can see it better if you use the intended notation

```
{
    "country" : 
    {
        "code" : "NZ"
    }
}
```

- `{ }` in json always wrap a json object (= class/struct). So you already know there have to be exactly **two** class/struct types in your case.
- you can see the first (root) type has to have one field called `country`. This field's type is the other class/struct's type.
- this second inner type has another field called `code`. It's type is a `string`.

And that's exactly what [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) already spit out for us ;)

---

Now you can e.g. use [`JsonUtility.FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

```
var json = "{\"country\":{\"code\":\"NZ\"}}";
var jsonObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<GDRPClass>(json);
```

and later access the data using e.g.

```
var code = jsonObject.country.code; // = "NZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

*"country"* is basically used as a key for *"{"code":"NZ"}"*, so they're on different levels of the tree.

You could deserialize this into a `Dictionary<string, CountryInfo>` (but not with with the built-in JsonUtility, that doesn't do Dictionaries, so I used Json .Net instead)

Have a look:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestDeserialize : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private string m_JsonStr = "{\"New Zealand\":{\"code\":\"NZ\"}}";

    void Start() {
        Dictionary<string,CountryInfo> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CountryInfo>>(m_JsonStr);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,CountryInfo> country in result) { //Log results
            Debug.LogFormat("{0}: {1}", country.Key, country.Value.code);
        }

        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)); //Serializes back into its original form
    }

    [Serializable]
    class CountryInfo {
        public string code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use *Pathfinding.Serialization.JsonFx* for JSON Parsing

`{\"country\":4,\"code\":\"Afghanistan\"}`
This will be the jsonString with respect to your Model class

```
GDRPClass data = JsonReader.Deserialize<GDRPClass>JsonWriter.Serialize(jsonString));
```